# Booting from the drive of an external hard disk with MBR

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, boot, mbr

A newbie to MBR/GPT here. I am living in the world of Ubuntu 16.04.

I use *Ubuntu Live CD* very frequently. Since I have an external HDD with lots of drives, my ingenious :) idea is to dedicate one drive on this HDD as a LiveCD so as to avoid carrying the tiny USB flash drives all the time in my wallet.

HDD is mounted as `/dev/sdb`. Below is what I tried.

> 1. Using "`sudo parted /dev/sdb print`", I found that this HDD has an MBR but not GPT on this HDD.
> 2. Next, using "`gparted`" I have created a drive "`/dev/sdb8`" (not primary, I could only make it a logical drive on the extended
>      partition)
> 3. Using "`sudo rsync -a`", I have copied all the contents of the LiveCD on to this drive "`/dev/sdb8`"
> 4. Using `gparted` -> `manage flags` option, I have set the flag "boot" on `/dev/sdb8` (This is the only drive with the flag set)
> 5. Rebooted with the drive connected on USB.

Alas! It didn't work.

In the One-Time booting options list of `<F12>` (Dell T1700 model), I don't even see the External HDD listed.. i.e., I cannot boot from here.

Someone, please help!

Clearly, I need to understand some basics, an explanation/pointer is extremely appreciated!!

Comment: When you're creating a partition in your HDD you need to create it at the beginning of drive rather than an end. When the BIOS checks your HDD to boot it doesn't generally look at the end of your HDD for OS.

Comment: The idea is good, but not quite correctly implemented. First, backup all the information on the disk. You need to make the entire disk bootable, set the disk `grug4dos` and set in the `menu.lst` ubuntu (the use of `grub4dos` allows you to add other LiveCD to the disk, which you may need to future). Replace all partitions simply with folders in which your information will be stored. If interested, later I can explain more

Comment: @Alex_Krug Hey Alex, thanks! Are you saying there must not be any partitions on a HDD that can be booted? I am very much interested, please explain.

Answer (score 2):

`Grub4dos` can be installed on a USB stick/HDD on the supported file systems. In this case, it is able to completely replace the original operating system loader. It is better to format in ntfs.

1. make backup somewhere of the entire contents of the disk (all partitions).
2. Any program or livecd (`gparted`, `acronis`, `paragon`, etc.) delete all partitions and create one partition on the entire disk in `ntfs` (may be need to make it active and bootable).
3. Download `grub4dos` zip arcive there:

https://sourceforge.net/projects/grub4dos/files/GRUB4DOS/grub4dos%200.4.4/grub4dos-0.4.4.zip/download

if you work in windows, you can use GUI installer there:

https://yadi.sk/d/dQYHiAFJTH8TR

4. To install Grub4dos to USB-stick/HDD run any operating system (Windows, any liveCD Linux), connect the target device - USB-stick or USB-HDD the contents of the package `grub4dos-0.4.4.zip` are unpacked into the available place for the used operating system.
   In the unarchived directory, the command is executed

   `# bootlace.com --time-out=0 --no-backup-mbr --mbr-disable-floppy /dev/sdX`

where `/dev/sdX` - is the target connected device

if you work in windows, you run GUI installer `Grub4DOS.exe` (sorry, the first window in Russian, but from the picture everything is clear) (through the `"Browse"` select the USB-HDD, extract the files)

http://lazvm-comp.ucoz.ru/_pu/0/s63791143.jpg

We put a bird in the `"Disc"` field and select our USB-HDD. In the list there will be also sections of your other hard disk, be careful, be guided by the volume. In this case, the USB test drive has a capacity of 4 GB (3812M). Other settings do not touch and click Install.

http://lazvm-comp.ucoz.ru/_pu/0/s53051361.jpg

After that, the necessary files appeared on the USB-HDD and it became bootable. It remains only to slip on the media necessary files to download the necessary operating systems and programs.

`Menu.lst` is the most important configuration file to work with. This is essentially a text file, you can open it using an ordinary notepad. `grldr` is the loader itself. In the `Boot` folder there is a subfolder called `gfx`, where the `Grub4dos` theme is stored.

You just need to copy the ISO image to the disk and add an entry to `menu.lst` that looks roughly like this:

```
title Ubuntu Mini Installer
find --set-root /images/ubuntu-mini.iso
map --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 /images/ubuntu-mini.iso (0xff)
map --hook
chainloader (0xff)
```

What this does is find the ISO, extract it, loopmount it in memory (first three lines) and then use a `grub4dos` trick by chainloading the bootloader of the image it just extracted. Typically this will load the instance of grub shipped with the ISO, which then boots the kernel. The advantage is that you don’t need to know where all files are located inside the ISO image, this is handled by the bootloader of the image itself.

“Fatter” live images typically ship the filesystem as a compressed image and play a similar trick to give you a working system. However if you run these images with the inception chain of bootloaders, the references to the various file systems get mixed up and the ISO will fail to boot with `“Unable to find a medium containing a live file system”`.

The solution is to not chainload the next bootloader, but have `grub4dos` directly boot the linux kernel of the ISO. This can require a bit of trial and error, because every distribution seems to have their own convention on where the files for their live images go (in `/live` or `/casper` or `/boot` or …). In order to boot a Ubuntu Desktop ISO, the `menu.lst` entry looks like this:

```
title Ubuntu Desktop Live
find --set-root /images/ubuntu-desktop.iso
map --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 /images/ubuntu-desktop.iso (0xff) || map --mem /images/ubuntu-desktop.iso (0xff)
map --hook
root (0xff)
kernel /casper/vmlinuz.efi  file=/preseed/ubuntu.seed noprompt boot=casper iso-scan/filename=/image/ubuntu-desktop.iso quiet splash --
initrd /casper/initrd.lz
```

The differences with before are:

`chainloader (0xff)` was replaced with `root (0xff)`: Rather than chainloading the bootloader of the (0xff) temp volume, the temp volume is set as the root volume for the next commands
kernel line: This is the kernel line from the grub instance on the ISO, with an added `iso-scan/filename` option
initrd line: This is the initrd line from the grub instance on the ISO
One way to figure out which options to pass to the kernel (and where all files are located) is to first chainload the included bootloader and inspect its boot configuration. You can then copy these parameters to the `grub4dos` `menu.lst`. Even though these settings differ between various distributions, the distributions themselves don’t change them very often. Once you have a working entry for your favourite distro, chances are you can wholesale reuse them when the next version comes out.

Source:

http://lazvm-comp.ru/publ/sozdanie_multizagruzochnoj_usb_fleshki_na_osnove_zagruzchika_grub4dos/1-1-0-38

https://wdullaer.com/blog/2010/02/26/boot-iso-files-from-usb-with-grub4dos/
https://wdullaer.com/blog/2016/08/17/boot-live-disks-from-a-multiboot-usb-as-an-iso/

My example `menu.lst`:

```
timeout=20
default 0
gfxmenu (hd0,0)/Boot/gfx/dragon.gz

title Windows XP BartPE Mini
map (hd0,0)/iso/bartpe_mini.iso (0xff)
map --hook
chainloader (0xff)
boot

title Win7 Live CD x86&x64
chainloader /XMPE/WinPE/bootmgr (0xff)
boot

title xubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386
kernel /ubuntu/vmlinuz iso-scan/filename=/ubuntu/xubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso boot=casper only-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz locale=ru_RU quiet splash --
initrd /ubuntu/initrd.lz

title Acronis Disk Director 12
map --mem --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 (hd0,0)/dd/ADD12_3270_ru-RU.iso (hd32)
map --hook
chainloader (hd32)
boot

title Acronis True Image 2017
map --mem --heads=0 --sectors-per-track=0 (hd0,0)/ti/acronis_true_image_2017.iso (hd32)
map --hook
chainloader (hd32)
boot

title Hiren's BootCD 9.3 Rus
map (hd0,0)/iso/Hiren's_BootCD_9.3.iso (0xff)
map --hook
chainloader (0xff)
boot

title MemTest86 5.1
map (hd0,0)/iso/Memtest86-5_1.iso (0xff)
map --hook
chainloader (0xff)
boot

title ERD 6.5_x86_Win7_RTM
map (hd0,0)/iso/ERD65_x86_Win7_RTM.iso (0xff)
map --hook
chainloader (0xff)
boot

title ERD 6.5_x64_Win7_RTM
map (hd0,0)/iso/ERD65_x64_Win7_RTM.iso (0xff)
map --hook
chainloader (0xff)
boot

title ReBoot
reboot

title ShutDown
halt
```

which corresponds to the directory structure:

```
[0000] # user directory with any files on my disk
[Boot]
    [gfx]
        dragon.gz # theme screen `grub4dos`
    BCD
    BCD.log
    memdisk.gz
[dd]
    ADD12_3270_ru-RU.iso
[iso]
    [HDDScan-3.3] # from here I run the program HDDScan under windows liveCD (Win7 Live CD x86&x64)
    bartpe_mini.iso
    ERD65_x64_Win7_RTM.iso
    ERD65_x86_Win7_RTM.iso
    Hiren's_BootCD_9.3.iso
    Memtest86-5_1.iso
[ti]
    acronis_true_image_2017.iso
[ubuntu]
    initrd.lz
    vmlinuz
    xubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso
[XMPE] # Windows 7 LiveCD
    [FONTS]
    [W7PePrograms]
    [WinPE]
        BOOT.SDI
        bootmgr
        grldr
        M1
        XM64.bat
        XM64.WIM
        XM86.bat
        XM86.WIM
    BCD
grldr
Menu.lst
```

You can add, delete any boot images by editing `menu.lst` by analogy